# Python - Creating a bunch of variables dynamically

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm new to Python and I have made a piece of code that looks like this:

```
class Ui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('logotest.ui', self)
    iposter1 = QPixmap('images/1.jpg')
    iposter2 = QPixmap('images/2.jpg')
    iposter3 = QPixmap('images/3.jpg')
    iposter4 = QPixmap('images/4.jpg')
    self.poster1.setPixmap(iposter1)
    self.poster2.setPixmap(iposter2)
    self.poster3.setPixmap(iposter3)
    self.poster4.setPixmap(iposter4)
```

The code does this: Set 4 images (1-4.jpg) as QPixmaps(iposter*) and use them for 4 QLabel objects(self.poster*).

However as I have a lot of images to process I wanted to use a function to do those jobs for me, so I wrote:

```
def setPoster(a):
    imagelink = "images/" + str(a) + ".jpg"
    iposter, a = QPixmap(imagelink)
    self.poster, a.setPixmap(iposter, a)
...
setPoster(1)
```

But this does not work as Python gives me an error of `TypeError: 'QPixmap' object is not iterable`. What should I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: You are trying to use unpacking. That explains your error. But instead of doing what you are trying to do, create a bunch of variables dynamically, instead, you should *use a container*

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment - how can I do that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `getattr` and `setattr` like this. I haven't fully under stand your requests. Why can you use `self.poster4` directly? I think the code below may help you.

```
for i in range(100):
    iposter = QPixmap('images/3.jpg')
    poster = getattr(self, 'iposter%d' % i)
    poster.setPixmap(iposter)
```

#### update

```
class Ui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('logotest.ui', self)
    def setPoster(self, a):
       iposter = QPixmap('images/%d.jpg' % a)
       poster = getattr(self, 'iposter%d' % a)
       poster.setPixmap(iposter)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I have edited my code to show that I used a Qt UI file and `self.poster4` is a QLabel object in the UI.

Comment: Hi - I got this error `TypeError: setPoster() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'`

Comment: You should add the argument a. You said that `I have a lot of images to process`, So you should list all your files using `os`. For example, if you have a file named `images/24.jpg`, you should call `self.setPoster(24)` instead of using `self.setPoster()`

Comment: Hi, I already used `setPoster(3)` but it gave me the same error

Comment: use `self.setPoster(3)` instead of `setPoster(3)`

Comment: Hi, I figured out what's wrong, it should be `poster = getattr(self, 'poster%d' % num)`. Everything works OK now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score -2):

all python variables are just dictionary keys. if you want you can add variables to an object like this

```
object.dict()["variable"] = 1
```

or if you want to do it globally

```
global()["variable"] = 1
```